# How to add formkey to a custom form?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, forms, form-key

I'm using the code...

```
<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

inside my custom `phtml` file but all I get is blank `''`. I see this same code used throughout Magento Core.

How can I enable this functionality in my template?

Comment: Are you using Magento 2 ?

Comment: Yes, I've tagged magento 2 and 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My XML was removing the `columns` block.

```
<referenceBlock name="columns" remove="true"/>
```

I'm not sure why, but this breaks a lot of functionality in Magento, including the ability to use `$block-getFormKey()` in an unrelated template.

UPDATE: I ran into this issue again and found that the `formkey` block was not defined. Added this to my xml and things worked.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\FormKey" name="formkey"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add construct function and try to add in your Customized Block file

```
 public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey){
    $this->formKey = $formKey
 }
 public function getFormKey()
 {
     return $this->formKey;
 }
```

call this function in your custom phtml file

```
 <?= $block->getFormKey() ?>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try. I'm confused because throughout magento core the function I was trying seems to work without these steps. Any idea why that is? For example: `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` via `Magento_Catalog::view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`

Comment: Throughout magento core extended AbstractBlock class. they will define the function in that. so we can also extend the same way they did. it also will work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same behavior recently, I removed some blocks and containers of XML layout. I was looking for get only a piece of a page without anything else (with update handle).
but instead of add a new block I just:

```
<move element="formkey" destination="myContainerOrMyBlock"/>
```

because I was defined in theme default.xml:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\FormKey" name="formkey"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Once I removed it with:

```
 <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper" remove="true"/>
```